# Cannot find module 'places.js' or its corresponding type declarations

Tags: typescript, angular13

I am using angular 13 version,in that package angular instance search is used,When i make build i got error like this.Please help me out to solve the issue.

node_modules/instantsearch.js/es/widgets/places/places.d.ts:3:30 - error TS2307: Cannot find module 'places.js' or its corresponding type declarations.

node_modules/instantsearch.js/es/widgets/places/places.d.ts:3:30 - error TS2307: Cannot find module 'places.js' or its corresponding type declarations.

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact issue as you. I solved it with the `skipLibCheck` in my tsconfig.json file:

```
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "allowJs": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "strict": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
}
```